# Как правильно записать конструктор класса с полем map?

Tags: c++, stl, map, шаблоны-с++

```
//hashtable.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

template<class kType,class vType>
class hashtable
{
private:
    map<kType,vType> *table;
public:
    hashtable(kType k, vType v);
    ~hashtable();
};
```

```
//hashtable.cpp
#include "hashtable.h"

template<typename kType, typename vType>
hashtable::hashtable() 
{
    // ??? Compiler Error C2955 ('hashtable': use of class template requires template argument list)
}
```

Could you tell me what is wrong there?

Возможно ли вообще и если да, то как записать `map` в качестве поля класса?
Так чтобы можно было написать `hashtable <char*,int>` и получался ассоциативный массив с ключем в виде `char*` и параметром `int`, но чтобы была возможность задать и другие типы?

по ТЗ, использовать `map` надо обязательно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша функция должна быть определена [как](http://ideone.com/KHrciZ)

```
template<typename kType, typename vType>
hashtable<kType, vType>::hashtable(kType k, vType v) 
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   чтобы соответствовало объявлению в классе
```